# allclose - How to check if two arrays are close in Julia

Tags: numpy, julia

In numpy you can do `np.allclose(A, B)` to see if the arrays A & B are close.

Is there any function in Julia to do so ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*(For the obsolete version of this answer, see below the horizontal line.)*

An array version of [`isapprox`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.isapprox) was [introduced](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/12472) in Julia 0.4, so you can now write:

```
isapprox(A, B)
```

Like in the scalar case, you can specify the relative tolerance `rtol` and the absolute tolerance `atol` as keyword arguments.

But note that unlike NumPy's `allclose` (and the previous solution of this answer below), array-`isapprox` calculates a norm of the difference first, and then decides for the resulting value. (Appearently, **checking `isapprox` pointwise [is wrong](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/12393)**.) By default, [`LinearAlgebra.norm`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/#LinearAlgebra.norm) is used, which is the 2-norm for vectors and the Froebenius norm for matrices, but you can override this behavior using the `norm` keyword argument.

By the way, as mentioned in the linked pull request, in tests you can write `@test isapprox(A, B)`, so `@test_approx_eq` is now obsolete and [deprecated as of 0.6](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4615). Also, there is `A ≈ B`, which is equivalent to `isapprox(A, B)` and can be used like any comparison operator: `a < b ≈ c ≤ d`.

---

*For reference, this is the previous, outdated version of this post:*

For single numbers, [`isapprox`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/math/#Base.isapprox) is defined. If you want to extend this to an element-wise comparison on `Array`s, you could use:

```
all(x -> isapprox(x...), zip(A, B))

all(x -> isapprox(x...), zip(A, A + 1e-5)) # => false
all(x -> isapprox(x...), zip(A, A + 1e-6)) # => true
```

Comment: You can also use the binary operator `≈` (typed as `\approx`<tab> at the REPL) when you're using the default tolerances.

Answer (score 6):

There is no function called `allclose` that ships with Julia:

```
julia> allclose
ERROR: allclose not defined
```

I don't know whether an existing Julia function provides the functionality you want but, based on the [`numpy.allclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) documentation, you can implement one yourself (complete with [keyword arguments](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/functions/#keyword-arguments)):

```
function allclose(a, b; rtol = 1e-5, atol = 1e-8)
  return all(abs(a - b) .<= (atol + rtol * abs(b)))
end
```

#### Tests at the Julia command line:

```
julia> A = rand(5, 5)
5x5 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0833821  0.722352   0.474616  0.0997349  0.352403 
 0.557657   0.199624   0.748646  0.838296   0.0396182
 0.9716     0.230623   0.215245  0.689457   0.261951 
 0.64731    0.0799202  0.877895  0.582062   0.601394 
 0.875966   0.776157   0.664024  0.0996859  0.12747  

julia> allclose(A, A + 1e-4)
false

julia> allclose(A, A + 1e-6)
false

julia> allclose(A, A + 1e-8)
true

julia> allclose(A, A + 1, rtol = 1)
true
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're writing tests, `using Base.Test` and then `@test_approx_eq A B` should work.